# (Java Reflection) Checking if a specific constructor exists

Tags: java, reflection

I have a project that uses reflection to load a few classes als modules. These modules can have a constructor with a specific parameter. If that constructor exists I want to create a new Instance of that class using that constructor, if it doesn't exist I want to use the default constructor.

Now I'm wondering how to check if that specific constructor exists. The only way I have found so far is doing it like this:

```
private boolean hasBotConstructor(final Class<?> moduleClass) {
    try {
        moduleClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Bot.class);
        // Constructor exists
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // Constructor doesn't exist
        return false;
   }
}
```

This works, but using try/catch seems like bad practice to me.

Comment: If you do this many times, and expect many throws, you might iterate through all constructors instead. Maybe check whether class `Bot` is imported.

Comment: The sounds like a job for [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: Should the constructor be public?

Comment: *"If that constructor exists I want to create a new Instance of that class **using that constructor**"* --- Since you want to *use* it, having a `hasBotConstructor()` method that looks it up, just to throw it away, is kind of a waste, don't you think? Make the method return the constructor. --- As for the "don't use exception for flow control" paradigm, I'd say that this is one of those exceptions to the rule. Using `try-catch` is ok here.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a better solution, but I am not sure what you mean with default constructor. If you have constructor with 1 parameter and default constructor has no parameters, than you can do it simply like this:

```
return moduleClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0].getParameterCount()==1;
```

This also suppose, that you have only one constructor declared.

If you have more constructors, than you have to check the whole array, if there is the one, that you want.

```
for(Constructor<?> constructor : moduleClass.getDeclaredConstructors()){
       if(constructor.getParameterCount()==1 && constructor.getParameterTypes()[0] == Bot.class){
             return true;
       }
}
return false;
```

This code also handle, if you need to check for the specific type in the constructor and it's the cleanest solution I, that I were able to write.

EXPLANATION:

getDeclaredConstructors return all constructors in the specific class. Than you check each constructors (by simple foreach loop) and if it fits your requirements you return true. You can easily modify it for different constructors by changing the number of parameters and than checking, if each parameter has the correct type by calling constructor.getParameterTypes().